# ggplot: How to implement rank based y axis and keep unused factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, rank

I am trying to build a simple scatter plot:
This is what my data looks like (`dlong`):

```
     Spender variable value  
1       1      IFN     2  
2       2      IFN     6  
3       3      IFN     5   
4       1      iL2  <NA>  
5       2      iL2     4  
6       3      iL2     8
```

which I originally melt from my dataframe

Since I am a selftaught, I made it so far:

```
  ggplot(na.omit(dlong), aes(x=Spender, y=value, coulor=variable, group=variable)) +
      geom_point(size=2, aes(shape=variable))
```

resulting in a graph

[image: reaction to proteins]

with enumerated test persons on the x axis,  with reactions to different time points (=value) (y-axis). These reactions differ by the typ of proteins (=groups = variable).

My real data looks aktually like this:

```
    Spender variable value  
1        1  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
2        2  ZP0.IFN        
3        3  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
4        4  ZP0.IFN        
5        5  ZP0.IFN        
6        6  ZP0.IFN        
7        7  ZP0.IFN        
8        8  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
9        9  ZP0.IFN        
10      10  ZP0.IFN        
11      11  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
12      12  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
13      13  ZP0.IFN  
14      14  ZP0.IFN        
15      15  ZP0.IFN        
16      16  ZP0.IFN   ZP0  
17       1      IFN   ZP2  
18       2      IFN  ZP21  
19       3      IFN        
20       4      IFN        
21       5      IFN  ZP14  
22       6      IFN        
23       7      IFN  ZP14  
24       8      IFN  ZP21  
25       9      IFN  ZP21
```

The values are actually ranked data
(with ZP0 < ZP2 < ZP4 < ZP7 ... ).

And here is my question. How can I implement ranked data onto the y axis?

What I did next:

```
dlong$value <- factor(dlong$value,   
levels=c("ZP0", "ZP2", "ZP4", "ZP7", "ZP14", "ZP21", "ZP28", "ZP35", "ZPM9", "ZPM91"))  
ggplot(na.omit(dlong), aes(x=Spender, y=value, group=variable)) +  
geom_point(size=3, aes(shape=variable))
```

1. Using R it wont open me the plot: so I added >png(filename="") with dev.off in front off and behind. Why wont the window wont pop up?
   [image: new scatter]
2. on the y axis it wont show me all requirde time points - it leaves also real points out (eg. Spender 1, iL2, ZP4)
3. How can I have marks on x axis for each "Spender"  with white thick lines in the grey field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there! You just need to turn the `value` into a factor with defined levels.

**The data**

```
dlong <- read.table(textConnection("1 1 ZP0.IFN ZP0
2 2 ZP0.IFN
3 3 ZP0.IFN ZP0
4 4 ZP0.IFN
5 5 ZP0.IFN
6 6 ZP0.IFN
7 7 ZP0.IFN
8 8 ZP0.IFN ZP0
9 9 ZP0.IFN
10 10 ZP0.IFN
11 11 ZP0.IFN ZP0
12 12 ZP0.IFN ZP0
13 13 ZP0.IFN
14 14 ZP0.IFN
15 15 ZP0.IFN
16 16 ZP0.IFN ZP0
17 1 IFN ZP2
18 2 IFN ZP21
19 3 IFN
20 4 IFN
21 5 IFN ZP14
22 6 IFN
23 7 IFN ZP14
24 8 IFN ZP21
25 9 IFN ZP21
","r"),fill=NA,na.strings="")[,-1]

colnames(dlong) <- c("Spender","variable","value")
dlong
##    Spender variable value
## 1        1  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 2        2  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 3        3  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 4        4  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 5        5  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 6        6  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 7        7  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 8        8  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 9        9  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 10      10  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 11      11  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 12      12  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 13      13  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 14      14  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 15      15  ZP0.IFN  <NA>
## 16      16  ZP0.IFN   ZP0
## 17       1      IFN   ZP2
## 18       2      IFN  ZP21
## 19       3      IFN  <NA>
## 20       4      IFN  <NA>
## 21       5      IFN  ZP14
## 22       6      IFN  <NA>
## 23       7      IFN  ZP14
## 24       8      IFN  ZP21
## 25       9      IFN  ZP21
```

**Convert to factor given defined ranks**

```
## The values are actually ranked data
## (with ZP0 < ZP2 < ZP4 < ZP7 ... ).
require(gtools)
dlong$value <- as.character(dlong$value)
dlong$value <- factor(dlong$value,levels=mixedsort(unique(dlong$value)))
```

**Then it is good!**

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(na.omit(dlong),aes(x=Spender, y=value, coulor=variable, group=variable)) +
  geom_point(size=2, aes(shape=variable))
```

[image]

**Edit:2014/02/12**

The 1)-3) questions in your edited post are regarding other aspects of plot/ggplot.

1) This is apparently an issue of the graphics device - either it is not installed or does not start properly. Assuming you have it installed, try the following to check if it will start/popup a device window,

```
X11()   # starts/pops up a X11 graphics device
plot(1:10)
```

You may get an error, which means `R` can not initialize such device. Then you need to use `pdf`, `png` (or etc.) instead of the popup approach.

2) To keep unused levels, use `scale_y_discrete(drop=FALSE)`

3) To have all `Spender` displayed, convert them to factor similarly as we did for `value`. And turn off the drop via `scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)`.

So continue with **The Data** above

```
dlong$value <- as.character(dlong$value)    
dlong$value <- factor(dlong$value,   
levels=c("ZP0", "ZP2", "ZP4", "ZP7", "ZP14", "ZP21", "ZP28", "ZP35", "ZPM9", "ZPM91"))
dlong$Spender <- factor(dlong$Spender)
ggplot(na.omit(dlong), aes(x=Spender, y=value, group=variable)) +  
  geom_point(size=3, aes(shape=variable)) +
  scale_y_discrete(drop=FALSE)+ 
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, without being able to ask someone from time to time its really hard. Somehow my browser does not support the editing required here, sorry in advance.

Comment: @newbymedicalstats `na.strings` is to tell `R` which string it should read as an `NA`. You may read more from `help(read.table)`. `[,-1]` is to ignore the first column, which is the row.names. In the **The data** section, I convert the data table you posted into an `R` table to reproduce your question. Since you already have your data object in `R`, you can dive directly from **Convert to factor given defined ranks** section!

Comment: Do you know any help on my updated problem above? Thx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I REALLY(!!) appreciate it. It finally worked. I will report the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the ranks instead of the values:

```
dlong$dummy <- as.numeric(gsub("ZP","",as.character(dlong$value)))

ggplot(na.omit(dlong), aes(x=Spender, y=dummy, colour=variable, group=variable)) + geom_point(size=2, aes(shape=variable))
```

[image]